# Facebook Access Token Invalidation Upon Password Change And How Pinterest gets new access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, pinterest

I want to know how Pinterest and other sites maintain there session and access facebook APIs even after the user changes his/her facebook password, since as far as i know facebook invalidates the access token issued once the user changes his/her password.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the exact implementation Pinterest uses, but if a user changes there password, the oauth token will be invalidated and you MUST have the user re-login. This is a security feature so for example, in the event of a hacked account, the user can change his/her password and all tokens will be invalidated (imagine what would happen if this wasn't the case... Your account gets hacked, they authorise there own scam app to have full access to your account, you reset your password... oh they still have full access to your account as they have a oauth token).

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) you can see what error is produced in the event of a password change and your app must detect this and handle it

Comment: thanks for the comment Lee i know what all you said in the above comment but what i am interested in is if FB invalidates the token then how these sites like pinterest still maintain the session when i change the fb password?

Comment: Pinterest is slightly larger than your site i imagine. They started in palo alto and moved to san francisco (IIRC), there's 3 reasons already why they might have more privileges than you do. Facebook does have the ability to keep oauth tokens valid, they do it for there own apps after all (facebook messenger?). Its not beyond belief, that Pinterest could have got this level of access. However you're not going to get it, so you will have to be ruled by their dev docs which state you must have the user re-login. Of course im just speculating, i doubt anyone outside of pinterest knows for sure.

Comment: Why do you think Pinterest retains their session? They could just be using the regular login code, which will give you a new token the next time the user comes back to your site

Comment: @lgy: not sure what you are referring to by "login code". The only "code" as such that pinterest will have for your account is the oauth token, which under normal circumstances would expire when a password is changed. You may be referring to the login details for the facebook user account? but if thats the case, then that's impossible as you don't provide pinterest with your FB login info (be no point in oAuth if you did!).

Comment: I checked the password change behavior again for pinterest,airbnb,newsle,klout they all ask for user to login if there is change in FB password (which is expected) except for FourSquare which even after i changed my facebook password was able to post on behalf of me to FB. wondering how FourSquare is managing to post even after i changed my facebook password.

Comment: @willsteel, the only thing i can think of is either, a) they are getting a new token when you visit very quickly so you dont notice the redirect (have you profiled the connection with dev tools after password reset?), or b) It may take a few seconds/minutes for facebook to expire all the granted tokens (doubtful, but they are fairly big, real-time de-auth might not be so easy at that scale).

Comment: @Lee with reference to point a, they cant do it quickly since in order to get the access token they should ask the user to login into FB. point b might be possible but not sure.

Comment: @willsteel, i believe if they request an extended token, you are not asked to re-confirm the app next time they ask for a token. Thats what the dev docs say, im sure

Comment: @Lee, the tokens can be extended if they have expired but in case of password change the tokens are invalidated so user has to login into facebook in order for the apps to get new access token and yeah user will not be prompted to re-confirm the app but he has to login with his new password.

Comment: @willsteel true, but if that user has changed their password then logged back in to facebook already, the oauth request won't ask them to re-enter there password, so it will go straight to token generation. Since they don't have to accept the app again, can you get a new token via iframe or ajax maybe? Like i said, im speculating, the only people that know for sure is those that have already implemented this style system.